# Ubuntu 23.10 - Timed out udev queue being empty

Tags: udev

The Ubuntu 23.04 boot was very fast, after installing 23.10, the boot takes, on average, 4 minutes and then the message appears: "Timed out udev queue being empty" and then it enters the log in window.

## System Details Report

---

### Report details

- **Date generated:**                              2023-11-09 11:40:25

### Hardware Information:

- **Hardware Model:**                              ASUSTeK Computer INC. Rampage III Extreme
- **Memory:**                                      12,0 GiB
- **Processor:**                                   Intel® Core™ i7 930  × 8
- **Graphics:**                                    AMD Radeon™ RX 580 Series
- **Disk Capacity:**                               1,2 TB

### Software Information:

- **Firmware Version:**                            0901
- **OS Name:**                                     Ubuntu 23.10
- **OS Build:**                                    (null)
- **OS Type:**                                     64-bit
- **GNOME Version:**                               45.0
- **Windowing System:**                            Wayland
- **Kernel Version:**                              Linux 6.5.0-10-generic

[Ubuntu is on sdb3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiwIa.png)